# How would a sea of ferrofluid behave?

Tags: physics, metals

Terrestrial world pretty much entirely covered in liquid, magnetic metal. Thin atmosphere and a relatively weak field of gravity, not quite the moon but less than earth for sure. Otherwise, how it would work on Earth is also sufficient.

Comment: Vote to close because the question "How would it work?" is too broad. Each question should have a single well-defined problem.

Comment: I asked a pretty succinct question there; how would it behave, fluid dynamics and such. I don't see what's broad about that @daron

Comment: It is not clear you are talking only about fluid mechanics. But even then consider the question "What are the fluid mechanics of the Earth's ocean?" and what kind of answer would be required to fully cover such a broad question. You could write many books on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

On Earth, it's hard to say how it would behave. Earth's magnetic field isn't too strong, but it's pretty spread out over a very very large area. Assuming you're talking about a moderately sized sea, you may notice some small spikes or deformations in the ferrofluid, due to the large volume and surface tension, coupled with factors like gravity.

If your planet's magnetic field is stronger and spread out over a smaller area, these effects would be magnified, especially as you get closer to the poles.

Additional advice: If this is for anything you're writing or creating, for more drastic effects, you may want to consider abnormalities in the planet's magnetosphere:

- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252152211_Negative_viscosity_of_ferrofluid_under_alternating_magnetic_field
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13231695_Negative-Viscosity_Effect_in_a_Magnetic_Fluid
- https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.271.5249.614 (paywalled)

Just a quick Google search brought up these papers (search terms "ferrofluid alternating field" and "negative viscosity ferrofluid"), and I'd recommend a more thorough investigation than what I did.